# Tool to measure performance of the web application

Tags: sharepoint-online, performance

Among these tool which one is most authentic to show correct data & is widely used to measure performance (both for on-premise and online):

- Fiddler
- DotTrace
- HttpWatch
- Developer Dashboard
- F12 in IE browser etc

Comment: Personally, I always start with IE Developer Tools when doing the performance profiling. This gives me a big picture what might be wrong with the page. Now, since I'm mostly developing Server-side code, the next step in fine performance profiling is to use Visual Studio Performance wizard. The report you get will show you most expensive methods in your code. This can give you a nice base for optimization.

Comment: not only server side code. How to correctly measure performance of the client side code?

Comment: Among the tool i have mentioned which one is dependable to measure JQUERY coding?

Fiddler
DotTrace
HttpWatch
Developer Dashboard
F12 in IE browser etc.

Please share your experience only among given choice. There are many tools but people says they don't show correct results so I am not interested with other 3rd party tools.

Comment: hi slaven semper,
Visual Studio Performance wizard runs like dottrace tool. Am I correct? is there much difference? please reply to my query.

Comment: Basically yes, they do the similar thing.